# Showing image preview on hover (HTML only)

Tags: html, image

Though there are many ways of doing this with CSS/JS, is there a way to do this just using HTML?

The reason that I want this is because it makes it much easier to copy.

Comment: Nope. I am doubtful that is it possible, but I am holding out hope.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm 99% positive that it is indeed impossible with HTML alone.

Comment: "makes it easier to copy" - What does this mean?

Comment: Copying the image would copy the image part, but not the associated JS/CSS (think reblogging in tumblr)

Comment: Ummm..nor would it copy HTML, right?

Comment: I believe that it does. Essentially, I want a rebloggable image with preview.

Comment: I don't know what "rebloggable" means either. Are you looking for something that's a self-contained html fragment?

Comment: I believe that would work also.

Comment: Then can you use `<style>` and `<script>` tags in your fragment?

Comment: I can try it, but I assume that it will work so long as it does reference CSS classfiles from another URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with just HTML.  You need at least CSS or JavaScript, sorry.  You might be able to get close with CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think it is possible with only HTML.

I want to address this:

> The reason that I want this is because it makes it much easier to copy.

First of all, it doesn't.

By separating CSS and HTML you are actually copying less every time you want to duplicate an instance of anything.

For example:

CSS:

```
 img{display:none;}
 a:hover + img {display:block; width:100px; height:100px; background:black;}
```

HTML:

```
 img{display:none;}
 a:hover + img {display:block; width:100px; height:100px; background:black;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U5cr6/)

Now if you want another image, just copy and paste the HTML right next to it.

However, the real benefit of separating content and style is the ability to edit once and change everything.

If I had fifty images across three pages on my website and I wanted to add a border to them, I would have to manually go into each page and change every single instance.

With CSS, I can change one line in one file, and they all update.

For this particular problem, however, I would look into a Javascript solution. Ideally image previews wouldn't load unless they are called on, and this is out of the scope of CSS.

Comment: Please read the comments under the question dealing with that statement. There's a particular reason the OP wants to do this (although it is, in fact, not possible in the way the OP wants).